# Cannot upgrade server earlier than 5.7 to 8.0 in centos. server start fail

Tags: mysql, centos

I try to configure Mysql server on centos 7.4. After installing Mysql 8.0 to my system, **systemctl restart mysqld** failed.

See the error log /var/log/mysqld.log.

> [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.11) starting as process 320
>   [ERROR] [MY-013168] [InnoDB] Cannot upgrade server earlier than 5.7 to 8.0
>   [ERROR] [MY-011013] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine.[ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
>   [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
>   [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.11)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.

Comment: I have the same problem here

Comment: The message are talking about you cannot do the upgrade from 5.6 or earlier versions. What version have you installed before the upgrade?

Comment: Have you tried to update first to version 5.7 and then to 8.0?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, do you have a solution?

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61392329/failed-to-initialize-dd-storage-engine

Answer (score 5):

You have to delete the files left from the previous MySql:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/*
```

Comment: Ok solution if you we okay with losing any existing data.