# Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine

Tags: mysql

So this is my problem (besides all my daily day real problems, that is), I am restarting MySQL daily. This error only occurs after installing WordPress.

````
2020-04-23T10:13:15.262414Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2020-04-23T10:13:15.262534Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2020-04-23T10:13:15.265798Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.19)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2020-04-23T15:31:38.383572Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.19) starting as process 22920
2020-04-23T15:31:39.709981Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting XA crash recovery...
2020-04-23T15:31:39.718659Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] XA crash recovery finished.
2020-04-23T15:31:39.961251Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-04-23T15:31:40.014645Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.19'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2020-04-23T15:31:40.148846Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060```
````

Comment: I am seeing the same error and having to restart the db frequently. Any solution?